# How find 1d array in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, 2d

I have a 2d array(3*3) and a 1d(3) array. And now I want to find 1d array in 2d array in columns and rows and order is not important. i.e.

```
A=[
   [0,1,2],
   [3,4,5],
   [6,7,8]
];
```

and my 1d array is like:

```
t=[7,4,1];
```

I want when search second array(1d) in 2d array return true, and now I don't know how do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new 1d array of hashes of each row of 2d array. Then hash source 1d array and search hash in 1d array instead of 2d.

```
var is_in_there = array_of_hashes.indexOf("source_hash");
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is extremely naive and rather boring to write.

It involves having 3 nested loops and comparing each element from each row (at first) of your matrix to those in the array and returning success if all of them have been found, then another 3 nested loops to compare each column with your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is my solution.

You can check the fiddle if you want to try: https://jsfiddle.net/arnaudbertrand/skgo9yay/

```
var d2 = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
];

var b = [7, 4, 1];

function inArrayWithoutOrder(d2, d1) {
    var match = false;
    d2.forEach(function (arr) {
        var temp = d1.slice(0);
        arr.forEach(function (e) {
            var i = temp.indexOf(e);
            if (i != -1) {
                temp.splice(i, 1);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (temp.length == 0) {
            match = true;
        }
    });
    return match;
}

function invertRowColumn(d2) {
    var newArray = [];
    d2.forEach(function (d1, i) {
    d1.forEach(function (e, j) {
            if (i == 0) {
                newArray[j] = [];
            }
            newArray[j].push(e);
        });
    });
    return newArray;
}
function inArrayColumnRowWithoutOrder(d2, b){
    return inArrayWithoutOrder(d2, b) || inArrayWithoutOrder(invertRowColumn(d2),b);
}
```

Then you can use: inArrayColumnRowWithoutOrder(d2,b)

You probably can make it look better but at least it seems to do what you are looking for